# Javascript error in IE9

Tags: javascript

Any body has any idea about this error,

> TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'pop': object is null or undefined:

Hi bru.scopelliti,

Here the code is:

```
someNode.innerHTML = _self.errorMessage + " : " + ioArgs.xhr.status + " : " +response.responseText;
```

The thing is the response object doesn't have responseText

Comment: could you share the code

Comment: @AlvinWong I'd say more like 50%. The other 50% would be accessing a property/method on an object literal.

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs when the object is null or undefined when you want to acces a property.

```
var x = undefined;
var y = null;
alert(x.pop); // error
alert(x.pop); // error
```

If you want to check if the object is null you can just do:

```
if (response) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

If you want to check if the object property exists you can do:

```
if (response) {
   var value = response.responeText || defaultValue
}
```

Edit: From the comments:

There's a few ways for checking for something being defined, but `if (something)` or `var x = y || z;` is not the way to go because falsey values `(0, '', etc.)` would cause this to not work. If you want to see if something is defined, I would use `if (typeof x === "undefined")`. For checking for a property in an object, I would use `if (x in obj)`, or possibly better depending on the scenario - `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))`. And for checking for null, I would use `if (x == null)`

Comment: Woooow....thank for your Express reply. Really i didn't try to access a property 'pop'. I am just trying to access response.responseText.

Comment: I don't think it would be an error...it would just be `undefined`. If you try to do something to it, like `x.pop.call(this)` or whatever, then it would complain.

Comment: @Ian: In Chrome, `var x = undefined; alert(x.pop)` returns `TypeError: Cannot read property 'pop' of undefined`, for me. Same for `null`. It might be browser-dependent. (Firefox also returns a `TypeError`)

Comment: @Cerbrus Yes, that's what we were just agreeing about. If you try to access a property or method on an `undefined` or `null` object, it's an exception. If you saw Arninja's original post, they were saying `x.pop` would throw an error for `var x = { foo: "bar" };` which wasn't right, because the object we're accessing, `x`, is defined. `x.pop` will be resolved as `undefined`

Comment: @Cerbrus, Ian is right, I just changed this answer quite a few times actually

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, there were just a bunch of edits in a short period of time, and in that time all those comments too :)

Comment: @ All, try this in chrome please. x = undefined; x.somevelue (x.a). You will get 'pop' undefined

Comment: @Arninja There's a few ways for checking for something being defined, but `if (something)` or `var x = y || z;` is not the way to go because falsey values (`0`, `''`, etc.) would cause this to not work. If you want to see if something is defined, I would use `if (typeof x === "undefined")`. For checking for a property in an object, I would use `if (x in obj)`, or possibly better depending on the scenario - `if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x))`. And for checking for null, I would use `if (x == null)`

Comment: @Ian I will add a notice section that refers to your comment ;)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check for any extra commas that you may have inadvertently added or forgotten to remove. IE does not honour it.

```
var foo = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2,
    c: 3, // this last comma will give an error in IE.
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, if it does so. i would get undefined or null. why it was "pop" undefined ?

Comment: @user1862748 I can't remember, but I think it would cause `foo`, in this example, to be `undefined`, and therefore accessing `.pop` of it would not be allowed